# How to add text into decision node UML in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, uml, activity-diagram

I try to use activity diagram in Visual studio. When I add a decision node to diagram, there is no way to add text to display true or false condition. I searched in connector properties but it doesn't help.
Look at this, I want to add `true` and `false` text into decision node:
[image]

Another way is using comment node, but the problem is comment doesn't link with connector.
How can I do that?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Click on the connector and `Right click->Properties`. In the Properties you can name the `Guard` on each connector.

Comment: work like a charm. How fool I am. I tried all connector properties, except Guard. Thanks very much, you're my hero.